# The authors didn't define as follows. Why? (cycle in a directed graph and in an undirected graph. "Introduction to Algorithms 3rd Edition" by CLRS)

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, definition

I am reading "Introduction to Algorithms 3rd Edition" by CLRS.

> In a directed graph, a path $\langle v_0,v_1,\dots,v_k\rangle$ forms a ***cycle*** if $v_0=v_k$ and the path contains at least one edge.

> In an undirected graph, a path $\langle v_0,v_1,\dots,v_k\rangle$ forms a ***cycle*** if $k>0,v_0=v_k$, and all edges on the path are distinct;

In a directed graph, $\langle 0,1,2,0,1,2,0\rangle$ is a cycle but in an undircted graph, $\langle 0,1,2,0,1,2,0\rangle$ is not a cycle.

The authors didn't define as follows. Why?

> In a directed graph, a path $\langle v_0,v_1,\dots,v_k\rangle$ forms a ***cycle*** if $v_0=v_k$ and the path contains at least one edge, and all edges on the path are distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked the fourth edition and here the authors define *directed graph* and *cycle* the same way as in the third edition. But they also provide some additional terms.

- In a directed graph, a path $\langle v_0, v_1, \ldots, v_k\rangle$ forms a *cycle* if $v_0=v_k$ and the path contains at least one edge.
- The cycle is *simple* if, in addition, $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_k$ are distinct. ... A directed graph with no self-loops is *simple*.

We see the authors use the notion *simple* directed cycle in this case.

Comment: epi163sqrt, Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @tchappyha: You're welcome.